# I turn off my computer while I was upgrading, what do I do?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I was upgrading my computer from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,but I turned off my computer during the upgrading, I fixed it so now it's completely back to 12.04.  However, when I try to upgrade again, it says:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f`
```

So now what do I do to upgrade it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants you to fix broken or missing packages before upgrade. In terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: `autoclean` is not necessary at that point, and you probably want `dist-upgrade` rather than `upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks a lot now it doesn't says broken packages anymore :) Even thought I can't upgrade my computer... the hardware can't or something like that because I got this computer free from school so it's impossible to upgrade it :(

Comment: There is nothing to stop a computer from upgrading that I know of. I would burn a copy of 14.04 to a bootable dvd from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Comment: Im pretty sure it happens with my computer because I got it free from school, everyone has the same computer. Thanks for the link :)